# RPM subpackages from a Python project

Tags: python, package, rpm, setuptools, distutils

When you deal with a big project and you need to create RPM packages for RHEL-based Linux distributions, it's often convenient to sparse your soft into [RPM subpackages](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-subpack-spec-file-changes.html) (for instance: *-client*, *-server*, *-devel*, *-debuginfo* etc). In this case you can get multiple packages that contain different parts of the project using the only **spec** file.

I would like to know if this functionality is supported in standard Python packaging modules (**setuptools** or **distutils**) in order to build multiple differing rpm packages from one project. 
I guess that something in my **setup.py** should correlate to this section of **spec** file:

```
%package server
%package client
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, distutils and its derivatives do not support that.  You would have two codebases, each with a setup.py script, producing two different sets of sdists/wheels/RPMs.  Or you could have one repository with e.g. setup_client.py and setup_server.py scripts (with different package name and list of files to package), but that is less common.

When we were developping distutils2, Tarek Ziadé wrote [pypi2rpm](https://bitbucket.org/tarek/pypi2rpm) to improve upon the bdist_rpm command provided in distutils.  There is no recent development, probably because it provides the feature his team needs, but you could contact him and see if he’d accept a pull request adding support for subpackages.

Comment: Also note that even though distutils2 is stopped, improvements of the Python packaging tools is ongoing, and there may be a discussion of the mapping from source packages to one or more binary packages in the future.  For now people are focused on installation and distribution.

Comment: unfortunately Tarek Ziadé has not got in contact and there are several unaccepted pull requests for his bdist_rpm2, so it seems like bdist_rpm2 is not intended to be improved. In case if I provide a patch with %package functionality to the distutils upstream, would you support the one?